# INSERT INTO if NOT EXISTS or increment if EXISTS

Tags: mysql

My question is. I have the table 'popular' with fields 'id', 'title', 'popularity' in MySQL. I need insert info into field "title", if info not exists or increment  value of 'popularity', if info exists. What is the best practice to do it?

Answer (score 0):

[**INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO popular (title, popularity) VALUES (:the_title, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), popularity = popularity + 1
```

Make sure you have an unique constraint on `title`

`id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` allows you to get the `id` of the record you inserted/updated using `LAST_INSERT_ID` (or the equivalent function for your MySQL API). If you don't need the `id` you can remove it from the UPDATE list.

Answer (score 0):

***sample code:***

```
if exists (select * from contact where name = @name) then
    select -1;
else
    insert into contact(name) values(@name);
    select last_insert_id();
end if;
```

***reference:***

*http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/88038/best-mysql-practice-to-insert-a-record-if-it-does.html*

*http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19243*

*http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/*

Comment: This will throw a duplicate key error if two threads call it at the same time with the same name. You need to lock the rows in the select and make sure the entire thing runs in a single transaction.